# I need to extract a value of the result of xml generated by http query

Tags: php, xml, variables, extract

I could really do with some help with this one, it's driving me mad!

I need to extract the value from an xml file that is generated by an http query...

I will explain...

I need to add a variable to this line:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.search&artist=ADD_ARTIST_HERE&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026

Which I can do with some variable editing in php

This will generate an xml file which looks like this:

```
    <lfm status="ok">
    <results for="rihanna">
    <opensearch:Query role="request" searchTerms="rihanna" startPage="1"/>         
    <opensearch:totalResults>3821</opensearch:totalResults>  
    <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage>30</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <artistmatches><artist><name>Rihanna</name>
    <listeners>3236233</listeners>
    <mbid>73e5e69d-3554-40d8-8516-00cb38737a1c</mbid>
    <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Rihanna</url>
    <streamable>1</streamable>
    <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/71057304.png</image>
    <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/71057304.png</image>
    <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/71057304.png</image>
    <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/71057304.png</image>
```

And so the file goes on...

From this xml output generated from my original query, I need to extract the URL in `<image size="medium"` and put it into another variable...

Sorry for a basic question (or what may be a long answer) but I really don't know how to go about this one at all...

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide me with.

Comment: You'll want to throw the result string into `SimpleXML` http://us3.php.net/simpleXML to make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [XPATH function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp) in php to reach that particular image link... the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) are sufficient to help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the XML string in `$str`:

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($str);    

foreach($xmlObj->results as $result)
{
    foreach($result->artistmatches->artist as $artist)
    {
        foreach($artist->image as $image)
        {
            if($image->attributes()->size == 'medium')
            {
                echo 'size medium: ' . (string)$image;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of loading the string you could grab the XML directly from the URL with [simplexml_load_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

Answer (score 0):

I use the Last.fm feed for an app I made and to get the images I used:

```
$imagexml = simplexml_load_file($imageurl) or $error = "Feed Not Loading";
$album = $imagexml->album;
$image = (string) $album->image[2];
```

$imageurl being the url for Last.FM and the $image will give you the url of that image

Comment: @peter Thanks, I have tried the following, but it doesn't return anything, please excuse my lack of knowledge...

'code'
        <?php

        $imageurl = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getimages&artist=cher&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026';
        $imagexml = simplexml_load_file($imageurl) or $error = "Feed Not Loading";
        $album = $imagexml->album;
        $image = (string) $album->image[2];

        echo $image;
        echo $album;
        echo $imagexml;

        ?>

Comment: `var_dump()` the `$imagexml` variable to see if is returning anything. Also echoing `$album` and `$imagexml` won't display anything as they are objects